# What will be the time complexity of this code regarding Recursive algorithm

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have carried out the money change problem, as in, to change an amount of money with the least number of coins possible. The denominations available are: 1,3,and 4. It's taking a long time to run even small amounts such as 100. Is the complexity 2^n?

```
def moneychange_rec(money,coins):
   if money == 0:
       return table[money]
   else:
       for coin in coins:
           if money>=coin:
               table[money] = min(table[money],1 + moneychange_rec(money-coin,coins))
   return table[money]
money = 11
table = [0]+[money+1]*money
print(table)
coins = [1,3,4]

moneychange_rec(money,coins)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the coin value from money in your if statement?

Answer (score 0):

The input size `n` is related to how many bits are needed to represent the value `money`. The recursion depth, though, is related to the value itself. Thus, your recursion depth *could* be exponential, and thus the algorithm is `O(2**n)`.

Looked at another way: doubling the amount of money from 100 to 200 will roughly double the amount of time your algorithm takes (or at least, roughly double the recursion depth). But in general, doubling a value increases the number of bits needed to represent that number by at most 1.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to solve this using memoization such that it reduces from 2**n? I know DP (bottom up) approach will do it, but I wanted to know about the thought process.